# how to understand the brackets in the last line and how to call the function

Tags: javascript

How to understand the  brackets in the last line and how to call the function.

I think it would be `fun()(1,1,handle);` if there is no `();` at last but what's the `();` mean?

```
var handle = function(boolean){
  alert(boolean);
}

var fun = function(){
  // Some definition
  // Some function
  
  return function(a,b,handle) {
    // Some process
    if (a == b) {
      handle(true);
    } else {
      handle(false);
    }
  }
}();
```

Comment: [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: "*I think it would be `fun()(1,1,handle);` if there is no `()` at last*" - yes, that is correct. But we normally want `fun(1,2,handle)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **immediately invoked function expression**, you can learn about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

It is used cause the function becomes a function expression which is immediately executed. The variable within the expression can not be accessed from outside it.

like this `fun` immediately executed.
for eg:

```js
function greatings() {
  console.log('Welcome to GFG!')
}
// Execution of Regular Function.
greatings();
// IIFE creation and execution.
(function () {
  console.log('Welcome to GFG! in IIFE')
})()
```

And for your question, the `()` is to invoke your function and you will call the function as `fun(1,1,handle)` like:

```js
var handle = function (boolean) {
  console.log('coming here')
}

var fun = (function () {
  // Some definition
  // Some function

  return function (a, b, handle) {
    // Some process
    if (a === b) {
      handle(true)
    } else {
      handle(false)
    }
  }
})()

fun(1, 1, handle)
```